# How to get a PortletPreferences without a request object

Tags: jsf, portlet, websphere-portal

I need to start a TimerTask that uses a PortletPreferences object.

here's what I have for now (MyUpdateTask here extends TimerTask):

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myManagedBean", eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyManagedBean implements Serializable {
    static MyUpdateTask updateTask;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        try {
            PortletPreferences portletPrefs = ((PortletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getPreferences();
            updateTask = new MyUpdateTask(portletPrefs);
            MyTaskService.getInstance().update(updateTask);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

`MyTaskService.update` uses a ScheduledExecutorService that generates a service to regularly update my data.

the problem I have right now is that `((PortletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getPreferences();` throws an **UnsupportedOperationException** because there is currently no request. How can I get a PortletPreferences without a request?

I do need a PortletPreferences object for the task.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Liferay Portal, then...

During the `RENDER_PHASE` of the portlet lifecycle, Liferay Portal executes render_portlet.jsp (which sets up the `PortletPreferences` object for the `RenderRequest`). [Lines 52-54 of render_portlet.jsp](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.0.3-ga4/portal-web/docroot/html/portal/render_portlet.jsp#L52-L54) look like this:

```
PortletPreferencesIds portletPreferencesIds =
    PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletPreferencesIds(request, portletId);
PortletPreferences portletPreferences =
    PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.getStrictPreferences(portletPreferencesIds);
```

So I recommend that you call one of the overloaded `PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletPreferencesIds(...)` methods that do *not* take a `request` object in order to retrieve the preferences associated with the portlet.

Since you don't have access to the `PortletConfig` you would need to hard-code the portletId as a `String` constant. If you need to get the portletId dynamically then instead of an `@ApplicationScoped` bean you could possibly `@Override GenericFacesPortlet.init(PortletConfig)` and start the TimerTask from there.

Otherwise, if not using Liferay Portal, then I am not aware of any part of the Portlet API that would let you get access to the `PortletPreferences` outside the context of a `PortletRequest`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't need to dynamically modify the timer setting, you could use an `<init-param>` instead. Then you could obtain the settings in your bean by calling `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext.getInitParam("myTimerSetting")` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am currently not using Liferay Portal. I am using WebSphere

Comment: You might want to see if WebSphere portal has a vendor-specific/proprietary API similar to Liferay's PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil described above.

Comment: @Sirmyself, you should note that starting the timer or task in the portlet's `init()` method might also work in IBM WebSphere Portal.

Comment: Isn't it what i did?

Comment: Oh ok, I'll see if I can do that

Comment: WebSphere Portal does have a model spi that should allow you to get it